# How to hide and show other elements upon focus on another elements like Stackoverflow.com's search bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, usability

I'm making a site where the size of input boxes for Name and Email is not engouh because of the design

So I want to know how to hide other elements of :focus and get back again after out of focus

Like this

[image]

**I want to do for both Mouse and Keyboard focus**

**Edit**

I saw the same effect which I want in Seach bar of Stackoverflow.com[image]

**How they are doing?**

Comment: Making this heavy on mouse use are you? You realize a hidden form element is out of tab scope--right?

Comment: But he don't need to set them to like display: none, he could just mix around with z-index, position and size. Then they will be in the tab scope--right? (I'm not saying this is an good idea, to hide or move around the form, but i like the challenge of coming up with a solution for this)

Comment: Why is this question tagged as html5 or css3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote some code in jsFiddle for this problem...

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/ycdrR/1/

update: http://jsfiddle.net/ycdrR/4/

Comment: I want to hide other elements when user start typing

Comment: when the user starts typing? oh... ok... you said on focus... it's easily altered...

Comment: See the search bar at top of http://stackoverflow.com and start to type u will see what i want

Comment: That's what I did... O_o ... or are you talking about the animation itself?

Comment: your example hide even i don't start type and yes like the same as SO

Comment: dude... then you can just change the focus event to keypress and you're done... as so: http://jsfiddle.net/ycdrR/4/

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/tBQpB/6/

in pure css:

```
.wrapper{
    width:400px;
    position:relative
}
input{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
input:focus{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    width:400px;
    float:left;
    left:0px
}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />

        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something in javascript like

```
$("input").focus(function()
                 {
                     var currentSelectedInput=this;

                     $("input").each(function()
                                     {
                                     if(this!=currentSelectedInput)
                                         $(this).parent().hide();
                                     });
                     $(this).css("width","100%");
                 });

$("input").blur(function(){
    $("input").each(function()
                                     {
                                         if($(this).parent().is(":visible")){
                                             $(this).css("width","auto");
                                         }
                                         else{
                                         $(this).parent().show();
                                         }
                                     });
                 });
```

used jquery for the above and the markup is as follows:

```
<div style="width="500px">
<div id="name" style="float:left">

    Name:
    <input  type="textbox" />
        </div>
    <div id="email" style="right">      
Email:
            <input type="textbox" />
    </div>
</div>
```